# What is the probability of an unemployed worker receiving no job offer during a time period?

Tags: macroeconomics, mathematical-economics, labor-economics, unemployment, bellman-equations

we are currently covering one sided search models and I had a question for you all. I kind of understand the raw calculus behind finding the probability of a job offer over a time interval h, but what about the reverse. Suppose we have a time interval h, what would the probability for an unemployed worker to receive no job offer during said time interval h? Would it just be 0?

Answer (score 2):

Unless I misunderstand the question these seem to be complementing events with probabilities $p$ and $1-p$.

Comment: Hello, I figured out my problem. I realized that I was supposed to be using a possion distribution.